# modal pop up like google

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to make modal popup like gmail (when we try to upload exe the pop up that generates covers scrollbar of the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following modal dialog plugins for jQuery:

- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)
- [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)
- [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)
- [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal)
- [Facebox](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/facebox)

Answer (score 7):

GMail runs on a `iframe` and the overlay `div` is not inside this iframe, so it stays on top o the iframe consequently on top of the scrollbar.

Code from GMail

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden; /* no scrollbars (only in the iframe) */
    width:100%;
}

.cO { /* this is the iframe */
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.Kj-JD {
    background-color:#C3D9FF;
    border:1px solid #4E5766;
    color:#000000;
    outline:0 none;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:450px;
    z-index:501; /* div stays on top */
}

.Kj-JD-Jh { /* the shadow */
    background-color:#808080;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:500;
}
```

Sample HTML

```
<body>
    <iframe class="cO">...</iframe> <!-- the scroll works on the iframe, not the body -->
    <div class="Kj-JD"></div> <!-- outside the iframe -->
    <div class="Kj-JD-Jh" style="opacity: 0.5; width: 1440px; height: 361px;"></div> <!-- black background -->
</body>
```

To show a div on top I recommend [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/), it does all the hard work for you.

Comment: I added a part of the gmail code, the body doesn't have a scroll, but the iframe does, and the div is not inside the iframe, meaning it can be placed on top of anything inside the body, consequently on top of the scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the modal option in jQuery UI Dialog or the JavaScript alert() function if you only need a simple text dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [modal option in jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal) or the JavaScript [`alert()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal) function if you only need a simple text dialog.